# TFS search bug for filename

Tags: tfs

How can I search TFS for a bug report where it has a file attachment with a specific filename? I've looked at tthe query fields and none are the filename, or anything like it.

Comment: Using WIQ, you can only query on the number of attachments not the individual files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the database directly, you can query the specific collection database. The table you are looking for is `dbo.[WorkItemFiles]`

The `ID` field contains the Work Item ID and the `OriginalName` contains the file name.

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM [Tfs_YourCollection].[dbo].[WorkItemFiles]
 WHERE OriginalName = 'Filename.extension'
   AND [Historical Removed Date] IS NULL
```

Comment: Yuck - that does it but it's definitely not easy.